# Embedding XSL code inside an <a> tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML data which includes URIs. I want to list the URIs on an ASP page, but also to make them clickable using `<a>` tags. However XSLT does not allow you to embed an XSL command within a tag, eg:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//uri">
  <tr>
    <td class="tdDetail">
      More information
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="<xsl:value-of select="." />" alt="More information" target=_blank><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I include the URL in the `<uri>` tag after the `<a href="` code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [the `<xsl:attribute>` element](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_attribute.asp) to have non-fixed attribute.

```
<a alt="More information" target="_blank">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</a>
```

---

**Edit:** As others have mentioned, it is also possible to use [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template):

```
<a href="{.}" alt="More information" target="_blank">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
<a href="{.}" alt="More information" target="_blank"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
</a>
```

**Try to use AVTs** (Attribute-Value-Templates) **whenever possible** (on all attributes except a `select` attribute). This makes the code shorter and much more readable.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using <xsl:attribute> (mentioned in KennyTM's answer) it is also possible to use the "{}" shorthand notation when working with attributes:

```
<a href="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
```

Comment: Also very useful to know. Cheers.